# C++ regex_replace to clean concatenated decimal numbers

Tags: c++, regex, character-class

As part of cleaning up an SVG path data string for display, I want to add spaces between concatenated fractional numbers.

An example would be "0.1.20" should become "0.1 .20" - basically add a space before the second decimal point when you have 2 decimal points separated only by one or more decimal numbers (i.e "2.0" should not become "2 .0")

I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

void splitString(std::string& pathString) {

  // ... some other clean-up, which works ...

  std::regex re3("(\\.[:digit:]+)(\\.)");$
  pathString = std::regex_replace(pathString, re3, "$1 $2");$

  std::cout << pathString << std::endl;$
}
```

But when I pass in a string with concatenated decimals like

M 46 -38.9 q 3.7.15 7.65.45 1.2.1 2.35.25 2.75.3 5.05.85 3.85.9 6.5 2.4

it is unchanged on the cout logging line. I'm using similar regexes for cleaning up other elements of the string and they all work correctly, so I'm assuming it's something directly related to the regex itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried a few more things, and found one that worked.

Adding a character class around [:digit:] solved the problem.

```
std::regex re3("(\\.[[:digit:]]+)(\\.)");
```

[:digit:] is apparently a class range, which must be wrapped in a character class to be parsed as an atom.

Comment: If you want to add a reference to this answer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript#Character_classes

Comment: Great idea! But it doesn't work correctly anyway, right? I mean, 5.05.85 should be converted to 5.0 5.85 and not 5.05 .85?

Comment: @anatolyg No, [the SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF) specifies greedy matching, so as many digits as possible go to the first number; `5.05.85` should be interpreted as `5.05` followed by `.85`.

Comment: @JaMiT I'm not sure if that's the link you meant to post (did you mean a SO answer?). I'm still a bit confused why a POSIX character range can't be treated as an atom, TBH.

Comment: @patros Hmm... Maybe you misread "this answer" in my first comment? When I said "this answer" I meant the answer I was commenting on (i.e. your answer [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58467817)); I was not implying that the link was to an answer. The link is to the reference. (If you prefer, I could post my own answer, but I thought I'd offer you the chance to improve your answer first.)

Comment: @JaMiT I did read the link, and I wasn't really able to understand why this behaves the way it does from the docs. Same for the second link. I'm not a regex expert, I can see how it works now, but I find the documentation hard to parse. Feel free to write an answer if you want to.

Comment: @patros I looked into this some more and it turns out that even POSIX regular expressions require the doubled brackets -- the choice of grammar was a red herring. What you added to your answer is good enough.